# Checking file duplicates for PDF/Word in Rails with Digest that have different properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, duplicates, md5, digest

Ok sounds simple for files that are saved already but what happens when you download a document and save it at different times, or edit it and then save it. The modified or created properties change

```
file_md5 = (Digest::SHA256.file "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{document_name}").hexdigest
```

But

The content is the same but document properties are different leading to a false negative on the check for it being duplicate.

Before you say "Why dont you do it on document name?" its not the use case here.

What are the best options to ensure that the document saved isnt being duplicated?